# Finding unknown variable in a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

$n^2x^{2n+3}-25nx^{n+1}+150x^7$

This polynomial has $x^2-1$ as a factor for:
1) no values of n;
2) n=10 only
3) n=15 only
4) n=10 and n=15 only

^which one's correct? 
Could someone please tell me how to solve this question :( so difficult

Comment: just put in the values for n and see if you can factor out $x^2-1$.

Comment: Use remainder theorem : $$0=n^2-25n+150=(n-10)(n-15)$$


$$0=n^2-25n(-1)^{n+1}-150$$

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a little more explanation to the comments:
remainder theorem approach: 
If $(x^2-1)$ is a factor of the given polynomial, we have:
$$n^2 x^{2n+3} -25nx^{n+1} + 150x^7 = (x^2-1)*f(x,n)$$
substituting, x=1 implies $n^2-25n+150=0$. substituting x=-1 implies $-n^2-25n(-1)^{n+1}+150(-1)^7=0$. 
The solutions to the former equation are n=10 and 15. For the latter consider two cases: n=odd$\implies$ n=-10 and n=-15 are the solutions and if n=even\implies$ n=10 and n=15. n cannot be 15 due to the assumption that n is even. Hence the only common solution is n=10.

Double check your solution by substituting:
For n=10: 
\begin{align}
n^2 x^{2n+3} -25nx^{n+1} + 150x^7 &= 50x^7(2x^{16} -5x^4+3)\\
&= 50x^7 (x^2-1)(x^2+1)*(2x^4(x^8+x^4+1)-3)
\end{align}

Please do check that n=15 is not valid by substitution.

Comment: I corrected my mistake (not checking the solutions corresponding to x=-1 substitution) but the factorization was correct.

Comment: please check the question again. The lowest order term is x^7. n=10 and x=-1 gives zero.

Comment: My bad again. Corrected it now.